# EF Core filter Enums stored as string with LIKE operator

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

I have a `Person` model with a `Gender` enum poperty which is stored as a string in the database.
I want to make a query to filter the data by a substring of the gender. For example if the `query.SearchLike` is `"Fe"` or `"em"`, I'd like to get back every Female persons.
Unfortunately the code below throws an exception.

```cs
builder.Entity<Person>().Property(x => x.Gender).HasConversion<string>();
```

```cs
public async Task<IList<Person>> ListAsync(PersonsQuery query)
{
  IQueryable<Person> queryable = _context.Persons.AsNoTracking();

  return await queryable
    .Where(x => x.Gender.ToString().Contains(query.SearchLike))
    .ToListAsync();
}
```

Exception:

> The LINQ expression 'DbSet\r\n    .Where(x =>
> x.Gender.ToString().Contains(__query_SearchLike_0))' could not be
> translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated,
> or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to
> either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or
> ToListAsync(). See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for
> more information.

Comment: what is the exception ?

Comment: That's the trouble with conversions. They make filtering virtually impossible.

Comment: And what can be a practical solution?

Comment: Store the `Gender` as an `int` instead of a string. Match the search against the enum and find all `Person`s matching whatever enum values matched your search. This should be much more performant too

Comment: Why are you doing a conversion ? Just define your enums as string properties. If you want to have string values. otherwise it is better for performance and even other things to store it in the database as an integers.

Comment: You can run "like" part locally (in memory) since you have a enum (fixed set of genders) and so can find which match without bothering database. Then just filter people with those genders (using equality, not "like")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution.
First need to cast the enum to `object` and then to `string`.

```cs
public async Task<IList<Person>> ListAsync(PersonsQuery query)
{
  IQueryable<Person> queryable = _context.Persons.AsNoTracking();

  return await queryable
    .Where(x => ((string)(object)x.Gender).Contains(query.SearchLike))
    .ToListAsync();
}
```

Related question in the [EF Core Github repo](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/20604).

Comment: This worked for me when updating a function from 2.1 to 6.0 when it wouldn't run with a ToString() being called client side (would throw LINQ Query client side evaluation error).

Answer (score 1):

From my understending, you should use EF Like functions. Try something like this:

```
public async Task<IList<Person>> ListAsync(PersonsQuery query)
{
  IQueryable<Person> queryable = _context.Persons.AsNoTracking();

  return await queryable
    .Where(x => EF.Functions.Like(x.Gender, "%" + query.SearchLike + "%")
    .ToListAsync();
}
```

Comment: `EF.Functions.Like()` expects two string parameters, but the x.Gender is an Enum. When I call the `x.Gender.ToString()`, then get an exception says 'The LINQ expression could not be translated.'

Comment: @KDani did you ever figure out how to implement this solution? It throws the same error for me

Comment: @Sora No, only the accepted answer worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `FromSql` method to execute a raw SQL statement

```
public async Task<IList<Person>> ListAsync(PersonsQuery query)
{    
    var param = $"%{query.SearchLike}%"
    return await _context.Persons
        .FromSql("SELECT * FROM Persons WHERE Gender LIKE {0}" , param)
        .ToListAsync();
}
```